# Move code to other class while keeping API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have a class that consists of far too many lines of code. Therefor I´m trying to refactor it into smaller chunks of functionality, without breaking the public API.

Suppose we have this code

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Now I want to move that method into another class, **without breaking existing code**. So clients of that method should still be able to reference that old method which then just calls the new method from the new class.

Of course I can mark the methods body, "extract method"(from R#) and finally mark the old method `Obsolete`.  Doing so on some hundreds of methods however is quite annoying.

I´m looking for something similar to Resharpers Refactor-->Move, but where existing code isn´t touched at all in order to not break clients of my assembly.

So in the end I need this:

```
class NewClass
{
    public static void DoSomething() { ... }
}
class LegacyClass
{
    public static void DoSomething() { NewClass.DoSomething(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is:
1. use Resharper to create an interface from the original class.
2. split the original class up into the new classes.
3. turn the interface into a shell of the original class.
4. use a keyboard macro in Notepad++ to turn:

```
void DoSomething();
```

into

```
 public void DoSomething() { NewClass.DoSomething(); }
```

This won't work for static methods though.

OTOH, you may be over-thinking the problem. 'Hundreds' sounds like a lot but at 10-seconds per function, it might only take an hour or so to do it manually. You could easily spend more than that attempting to automate it or looking for a perfect solution.

Comment: "You could easily spend more than that attempting to automate it or looking for a perfect solution." You may be right. But I suppose I have also a hundred of files to refactor, so on long-term I suppose something more automatic would be really nice. Anyway most of methods unfortunately **are** `static`.

Comment: If it would take more than an hour or two, it is worth writing a simple console app to help you. (open file, read lines until you find a function, count brackets to find the end, write to new file, etc...).